# Cannot Connect ODBC Driver

Tags: php, mysql, datasource

I cannot access the ODBC Driver. I have a 64 bit Windows 7 System. To connect to a ODBC 5.1 Driver I used `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32`. I created a User DSN with name AJOY. There was no problem with that. Everything worked fine for the past 3 months. But now when I use

`odbc_connect()`

to connect with the same User DSN name i have a problem. I usually connect by the statement

`$conn=odbc_connect("Ajoy","","");`

There was no problem with the statement earlier. But now When I run my code it returns like

`odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect`

When I check the Data Sources (ODBC) in control panel, I can see the User DSN that I created but I cannot remove it. When i click remove it throws an error like

`The setup routines for the MySQL 5.1 Driver ODBC could not be found. Please re-install the driver`

It also returns there is an architecture mismatch between the driver and the application. I tried various steps but still it is not working. How to fix this? Help me please!!

Comment: ave you tried running odbcad32 as administrator?

Comment: I tried running odbcad32 as administrator. I can remove the existing User DSN and also i created a new User DSN named "Test". I tried to connect with this new User DSN "Test", but still the same error occurs. Any other option??

Comment: Have you tried using a System DSN instead of a User DSN? Are you also running the same bitness of ODBC Administrator as your driver and app? They must all match (you can have a 32-bit DSN or 64-bit DSN).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is what odbcad32 you are using.  You must use the one in the c:\Windows\System32 for a 64 bit application; not the c:\windows\SysWow64 directory.
There are 2 versions, one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit applications.